# Dashing on Heroku giving "config.ru" error

Tags: ruby, heroku, dashing

So, I am just trying to get a simple Heroku server running Dashing up. So far, I have the dashing and gemlock committed to heroku. Whenever I open the site, I get an error. My logs give me this:

> 2015-03-14T04:05:37.617789+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2447a74 by @gmail.com
>   2015-03-14T04:05:37.617789+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by @gmail.com
>   2015-03-14T04:05:38.099916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2015-03-14T04:05:41.184158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e pr
>   oduction -p 12627`
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.367997+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32
>   :in `read': No such file or directory - config.ru (Errno::ENOENT)
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368046+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/rack/adapter/load
>   er.rb:32:in`load'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368055+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/runner.rb:20
>   0:in `run_command'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368051+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/controllers/
>   controller.rb:182:in`load_rackup_config'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368053+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/controllers/
>   controller.rb:72:in `start'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/bin/thin:6:in`'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368066+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/runner.rb:15
>   6:in`run!'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:43.368069+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `'
>   2015-03-14T04:05:44.164461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2015-03-14T04:05:44.157004+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   2015-03-14T04:06:01.687293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-d
>   awn-3700.herokuapp.com request_id=902320e9-1789-4099-94b2-8b4431d59495 fwd="66.190.95.133" dyno= connect= service= statu
>   s=503 bytes=
>   2015-03-14T04:06:02.015965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" hos
>   t=pacific-dawn-3700.herokuapp.com request_id=6563d675-9732-4a21-84f4-c486fb6d792e fwd="66.190.95.133" dyno= connect= ser
>   vice= status=503 bytes=

A config.ru file was never created...I'm new to Ruby and Dashing and Heroku. I've even tried creating a blank config.ru, but even more errors occur...

Comment: config.ru file is used by rack middleware. Which framework you are using with ruby?

Comment: I believe Dashing is using Sinatra?

Answer (score 0):

Found the config file in anothjer directory somehow. Popped it in, it works!